# Ubuntu K/FreeBSD

Tags: debian, ubuntu, freebsd, darwin, hurd

I was wondering if it is possible to alter Debian K/FreeBSD so it becomes Ubuntu? I know there are builds of Debian 7 running on FreeBSD, so would it be possible to get a working Ubuntu system with the experimental DKFBSD 7 with the 14.04 userland?

If this is doable, can the same be done with the Hurd or Minix, or Darwin kernels?

Comment: You're basically asking how to switch kernels, keeping the rest of the distribution intact? I would say it is no trivial feat, and would likely need a lot of tweaking and testing before it could work.

Answer (score 1):

You would need someone to precompile source of all packages and get .debs ready for you (the Debian binary packages for Linux kernels won't work for FreeBSD kernels), and recompiling/porting is not always trivial. Ubuntu doesn't have those precompiled binaries, so I think the simple answer is "no -- at least not without a team of very competent developers".

You can, however, try to use Debian GNU/kFreeBSD and install the same packages that you'd have in an Ubuntu system. However, that distribution is not yet in great shape.

The same is true for other kernels -- there is Debian GNU/Hurd, but there is no precompiled Ubuntu packages for the Hurd, and several Debian packages are not available for Debian GNU/Hurd.